Can someone explain the meaning of “crease” in the following problem?
I'm having difficulty understanding this problem, in the sense of interpretation in English:
The lower right-hand corner of a page is folded over so that it just touches the left edge of the paper, as in Figure 30. If the width of the paper is $\alpha$ and the page is very long, show that the minimum lenght of the crease is $\frac{3\sqrt{3}\alpha}{4}$.
There is a picture, what is “crease”?
Ps(the picture is too big, does there any feature that can be used to resized?)


The crease is the hypotenuse of the bottom right right-angled triangle i.e. the dark line going from the base of the rectangle to the right-hand side of the rectangle.

I'm curious how looking up "crease" in a dictionary didn't answer this for you.

In origami, a crease is a line that remains after you fold the paper and unfold it. Like fold, it's both a noun and a transitive verb, e.g., instructions might read: Crease the paper between opposite pairs of corners to find the center.
As mentioned in the comments, the crease in this diagram is the hypotenuse of the small right triangle in the corner. If this were real paper, once you unfolded that corner, the crease (line segment) would remain.
Incidentally, all of Euclidean geometry (and more, e.g., trisecting angles) can be accomplished using folds and creases, and it has been axiomatized.

By the way, even as a native English speaker, I find the English Language & Usage stack exchange site to be a gold mine for learning subtle aspects of the language. The community over there is very helpful.
